# Go subpackage functions not imported properly

Tags: go

Trying to wrap my head around packages in Golang.

This is my workspace

```
/bin
/pkg
/src
  /github.com
    /esbenp
      /testrepo
        /subpackage
          somefuncs.go
        main.go
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import "github.com/esbenp/testrepo/subpackage"

func main() {
  Somefunc()
}
```

**somefuncs.go**

```
package subpackage

import "fmt"

func Somefunc() {
  fmt.Printf("yo")
}
```

I was under the impression that since `Somefunc` starts with an uppercase letter it would be exported for use in other files that imported it. The ouput I get in the console is.

```
main.go:4: imported and not used: "github.com/esbenp/testrepo/subpackage"
main.go:8: undefined: Somefunc
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do not call it "subpackage", not even mentally. There is no real notion of "sub"-package. Package have to live somewhere and these directories are nested in the filesystem. But this filesystem nesting has no meaning on how you use, import and access the packages. (Nitpick: The go tool treats some filesystem folders like vendor, internal or testdata special and has a notion of subpackage).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to prefix the function by the name of the package is belongs to: `subpackage.Somefunc()`.

In the case you have several subpackages with the same name, you have to alias them while importing them, or there will be a conflict:

```
import (
    xapi "x/xx/xxx/api"
    yapi "y/yy/yyy/api"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you import a package it will be made available under its name.

To address Somefunc in your main.go you have to do

`subpackage.Somefunc()`